# Program to find minimum number of move-to-front to arrange items in array and sort it

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, algorithm, sorting

I m trying to achieve a sort mechanism where in an unsorted array only one element at a time is picked and placed in front of the array, need to achieve this in minimum iterations.

```
[3,1,3,2] //input array
[2,3,1,3]// step one
[1,2,3,3]// step tow and the result, iterations = 2
```

The sample try which I gave was, which doesn't seems to work -

```
let sort = (inputArr) => {
    let originalArr = inputArr;
    let arrCopy = [...inputArr];
    let sortedArr = [...inputArr];
    sortedArr.sort();// need to achive here 

    let interations = 0;

    //find 2nd max number
    let secLarNum;

    Math.max(...arrCopy);

    arrCopy = removeItem(arrCopy, Math.max(...arrCopy));

    while(JSON.stringify(sortedArr) !== JSON.stringify(originalArr)) {
        let index = 0;
        secLarNum = Math.max(...arrCopy);
        arrCopy = removeItem(arrCopy, Math.max(...arrCopy));

        index = originalArr.indexOf(secLarNum);

        for(let i=0; i < originalArr.length; i ++){
            if(originalArr[index] > originalArr[i] && index !== -1){
                let currValue = originalArr[index];
                originalArr.splice(index, 1);
                originalArr.unshift(currValue);
                interations ++;
                // break;
            }
        }

    }
    console.log('Sorted array ', originalArr);
    return interations;

}


let removeItem = (array, item) => { 
    return array.filter((i) => i !== item);
}

console.log(sort([3,3,2,1,4])); // 2
```

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is vague - what specifically is wrong with it? Does it throw an exception, give the wrong result, get stuck in an infinite loop, or something else? Please edit the question to make it more specific. Include an input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: @kaya3 it actually goes into an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
function moveOne() {
    let idx = -1;
    let candidate = undefined;
    let max = arr[0];

    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let e = arr[i];
        if (e > max)
            max = e;

        if ((candidate == undefined || candidate < e) && e < max) {
            idx = i;
            candidate = e;
        }
    }

    if (idx == -1)
        return false;

    arr.splice(idx, 1);
    arr.unshift(candidate);
    return true;
}

let arr = [ 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6 ] ;
do {
    console.log(arr);
} while(moveOne());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but there seems to be a couple of errors with this -
1. it's pushing the elements to the back of the array, but the question requires at the front.
2. The script enter an infinite loop when different array inputs are given e.g- `[3,1,3,2,4,5]`

Comment: Yeah, it's my fault :) What is the next step for `[3,2,3,1]`?

Comment: should be `[2,3,3,1]` and then the final one `[1,2,3,3]`

Comment: Why not a `[1,3,2,3]`? What is the difference?

Comment: I question or rather the requirement is like that, we can only add elements in the **front** of an array

Comment: Why do you prefer move `2` in the front but not `1`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203333/discussion-between-ayush-and-aikon-mogwai).